# Display error message on invalid special field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

I would know how display a error message on my invalid field

I have a simple form

```
  <%= simple_form_for @bien do |f| %>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.input :adress, :input_html =>{:id => 'address'}, placeholder: 'Adresse', label: "Adresse" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <div class="form-group">
        <h5><b>Type de mandat</b></h5>
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

        <label class="btn btn-danger active" style="margin-right: 10px;">
          <input id="bien_mandat_type_true" name="bien[mandat_type]" type="radio" autocomplete="off" value="Simple"/> Simple
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-danger"  style="margin-right: 10px;">
          <input id="bien_mandat_type_true" name="bien[mandat_type]" type="radio" autocomplete="off" value="Exclusif" /> Exclusif
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-danger">
          <input id="bien_mandat_type_true" name="bien[mandat_type]" type="radio" autocomplete="off" value="Délégation" /> Délégation
        </label>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Valider", class: "btn btn-fill callpremium btn-danger btn-lg" %>
  </div>

  <% end %>
```

And i would display a error message when my input is empty like i do with the normal adress field, i wont use flash messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple form error messages are driven by your model's validations.  Add a [presence validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence) to the fields you want to have errors when empty and simple form will respond accordingly automatically.  For example, you could add this to your model to give an error when address is empty:

```
 validates :address, presence: true
```